# How can I make a simple analog to digital converter?

Tags: adc

I'm trying to hook up a sip-puff air pressure sensor ([datasheet](http://www.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/data_sheet/MPXV7025.pdf?fpsp=1&WT_TYPE=Data%20Sheets&WT_VENDOR=FREESCALE&WT_FILE_FORMAT=pdf&WT_ASSET=Documentation)) which outputs 0v to 5v depending if the pressure is -ve (sipping) or +ve (puffing). I want to use it to drive a Bluetooth keyboard controller ([info](http://www.adafruit.com/product/1535)) to help a disabled person use an iPad. When pins on the Bluetooth controller are driven low, they send a key press - the idea being when you sip it sends key 'a' and when you puff it sends 'b'.

I need some help coming up with a simple circuit to interface the two, thus:

- When the sensor output is 0v - V1 then drive pin 1 'a' low (sip)
- When the sensor output is V1 - V2 then do nothing (dwell / dead zone)
- When the sensor output is V2 - 5v then drive pin 2 'b' low (puff)

I'd also like a couple of trimming pots in the circuit to set V1 and V2. I have transistors and resistors to hand so it would be helpful if I can build using those, otherwise it's no problem to get other components if needed.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that is a classic task for comparators.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBMNju.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the resistors don't have the correct values you need, you will have to calculate them according to your needs.

Comparators will output "1" (supply voltage) if the + voltage is higher than the - voltage. Otherwise they will output "0".

So for this task you will need 2 comparators, one configured to look if the output is lower than V1, that's CMP1. And one that looks if the voltage is higher than V2, that's CMP2s job.

With the potentiometers you can vary the voltages V1 and V2.

For a task like that, I'd also use a hysteresis as signal outputs tend to be noisy and you probably don't want that near the voltage V1 or V2 the signal trips often because it's varying slightly around that point. So basically the hysteresis will serve as a debouncing.

There are comparators available which have a built in hysteresis, but you can add one with using just resistors to any comparator.

Using just transistors and resistors, you might as well be able to do that, but I'm really not good at those levels of electronics.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation of comparators - I'm looking at datasheets now, however Dave might have a point with microprocessors seeing as these days it's possible to pick up an Arduino Mini for not much more than a comparator IC!

Comment: That's quite true, and the reason why I upvoted his answer. Don't know why I didn't think of that as I'm doing nearly everything with microcontrollers these days.

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking for is called a "dual comparator", and you can get them as single chips.

However, you should seriously consider using a small microcontroller with a built-in ADC. This would allow you to adjust the two thresholds in software (possibly by remote control), or even to create an adaptive algorithm that doesn't need as much manual adjustment.

If your disabled person is willing to learn Morse Code, your microcontroller could be programmed to decode it and send a much broader range of characters to the Bluetooth interface.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I was trying to avoid using a microcontroller if possible, but I think you could be on to something, especially given I can get an Ardunio Mini for less then the price of a coffee. The Bluetooth board has a serial input, which makes like easier. As for Morse Code - great suggestion but wrong audience for the person I'm trying to help! Besides, the voice recognition in the iPad is very good.